# Insert several variation and sign tables in a tabular

Tags: tables, tkz-tab

I want to make a big tabular where there are multiples variation and sign tables, using the package`tkz-tab`.
I've tried this, but it's very painful and quasi-impossible to align perfectly columns of the big tabular, and the columns of sign and var tables. And there is also plenty of double lines in a same place.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{6.57cm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{3.55cm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{3.57cm}<{$}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|E|F|G|H|}
\hline
\text{factorisation} & a\big(x-\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big)\big(x-        \frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big) & a\big(x-\alpha\big)^2 & \text{N'existe pas dans $\mathbb{R}$}\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 2.35, espcl = 1.5]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /1, $f$ /1.5}{$-\infty$, $x_1$, $\alpha$, $x_2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, +, z, , -, , z, +, } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, R/, -/ $\beta$, R/, +/ $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{$0$}
   \tkzTabIma{3}{5}{4}{$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}}
& 
\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.49]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, +, z, +, } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -/ 0, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, , +, , } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -/ $\beta$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 2.35, espcl = 1.5]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /1, $f$ /1.5}{$-\infty$, $x_1$, $\alpha$, $x_2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, -, z, , +, , z, -, } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, R/, +/ $\beta$, R/, -/ $-\infty$}
   \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{$0$}
   \tkzTabIma{3}{5}{4}{$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}}
&
\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.49]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, -, z, -, } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +/ 0, -/ $-\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
&
\!\!\!\!\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, , -, , } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +/ $\beta$, -/ $-\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've also tried to make different mini-tabular and tables. But it needs to adjust all column's sizes of the different tables.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{E}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{6.57cm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{3.55cm}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{3.57cm}<{$}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|E|F|}
\hline
& \Delta >0 \\
\hline
|$S$| & 2\\
\hline
\text{factorisation} & a\big(x-\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big)    \big(x-\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big)\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\!
\begin{tabular}{|G|}
\hline
\Delta =0\\
\hline
1\\
\hline
a\big(x-\alpha\big)^2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\!
\begin{tabular}{|H|}
\hline
\Delta <0\\
\hline
0\\
\hline
\text{N'existe pas dans $\mathbb{R}$}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 2.35, espcl = 1.5]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /1, $f$ /1.5}{$-\infty$, $x_1$, $\alpha$, $x_2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, +, z, , -, , z, +, } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, R/, -/ $\beta$, R/, +/ $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{$0$}
   \tkzTabIma{3}{5}{4}{$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, +, z, +, } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -/ 0, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, , +, , } 
   \tkzTabVar{+/ $+\infty$, -/ $\beta$, +/ $+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 2.35, espcl = 1.5]{$x$ /1, $f(x)$ /1, $f$ /1.5}{$-\infty$, $x_1$, $\alpha$, $x_2$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, -, z, , +, , z, -, } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, R/, +/ $\beta$, R/, -/ $-\infty$}
   \tkzTabIma{1}{3}{2}{$0$}
   \tkzTabIma{3}{5}{4}{$0$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, -, z, -, } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +/ 0, -/ $-\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzTabInit[lgt = 0, espcl = 1.5]{/1, /1, /1.5}{$-\infty$, $\alpha$, $+\infty$}
   \tkzTabLine{, , -, , } 
   \tkzTabVar{-/ $-\infty$, +/ $\beta$, -/ $-\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So, is there a way to have a nice big tabular with all columns of sign and var tables nicely aligned and side by side?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not quite clear to me what went wrong with your first attempt. I suggest to go ahead with your single `tabular`environment and to post a question as soon as you get stuck with this approach.

Comment: Edited. Is it clearer?

Comment: Why don't you start with a plain `\begin{tabular}{cccc}` with 9 rows and fill the cells? Don't care for the lines for the moment, there are too many anyway: vertical lines are mostly unnecessary, and you maybe need only two horizontal lines to separate the three blocks (consisting of three rows each). If you observe some misalignment, come back and ask how to adjust the alignment in this particular column. It is still not clear what your initial problem was that lead you to nested tabulars/arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch what I meant in my comment regarding starting with a 9x4 table and using lines sparingly.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\mynode[3]{\node(#1) at (#2) {\raisebox{0ex}[0.7ex][0ex]{$#3$}};}
\newcommand\xgt
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
     \mynode{a}{-2,0}{-\infty}
     \mynode{b}{-1,0}{x_1}
     \mynode{c}{ 0,0}{\alpha}
     \mynode{d}{ 1,0}{x_2}
     \mynode{e}{ 2,0}{+\infty}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand\xeq
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
     \mynode{a}{-1,0}{-\infty}
     \mynode{b}{ 0,0}{\alpha}
     \mynode{c}{ 1,0}{+\infty}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\let\xlt\xeq
\newcommand\fxgt[2]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
     \mynode{a}{-1.5,0}{#1}
     \mynode{b}{-1  ,0}{0}
     \mynode{c}{ 0  ,0}{#2}
     \mynode{d}{ 1  ,0}{0}
     \mynode{e}{ 1.5,0}{#1}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand\fxeq[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
     \mynode{a}{-0.5,0}{#1}
     \mynode{b}{ 0  ,0}{0}
     \mynode{c}{ 0.5,0}{#1}
   \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand\fgta%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=3ex]
     \mynode{a}{-2,1  }{+\infty}
     \mynode{b}{-1,0.5}{0}
     \mynode{c}{ 0,0  }{\beta}
     \mynode{d}{ 1,0.5}{0}
     \mynode{e}{ 2,1  }{+\infty}
     \draw[->] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
     \draw[->] (c) -- (d) -- (e);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\newcommand\fgtb%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-3ex]
     \mynode{a}{-2,-1  }{-\infty}
     \mynode{b}{-1,-0.5}{0}
     \mynode{c}{ 0, 0  }{\beta}
     \mynode{d}{ 1,-0.5}{0}
     \mynode{e}{ 2,-1  }{-\infty}
     \draw[->] (a) -- (b) -- (c);
     \draw[->] (c) -- (d) -- (e);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\newcommand\feqlta[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=3ex]
     \mynode{a}{-1,1}{+\infty}
     \mynode{b}{ 0,0}{#1}
     \mynode{c}{ 1,1}{+\infty}
     \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
     \draw[->] (b) -- (c);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\newcommand\feqltb[1]%
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-3ex]
     \mynode{a}{-1,-1}{-\infty}
     \mynode{b}{ 0, 0}{#1}
     \mynode{c}{ 1,-1}{-\infty}
     \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
     \draw[->] (b) -- (c);
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\newcommand\feqa{\feqlta{0}}
\newcommand\flta{\feqlta{\beta}}
\newcommand\feqb{\feqltb{0}}
\newcommand\fltb{\feqltb{\beta}}

\begin{center}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
\begin{tabular}{cc@{\quad}c@{\quad}c}
  \toprule
         & $\Delta>0$ & $\Delta=0$  & $\Delta<0$ \\
   $|S|$ &     $2$    &     $1$     &     $0$    \\
  factorisation
         & $a\big(x-\frac{-b-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big)\big(x-\frac{-b+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\big)$
                      & $a\big(x-\alpha\big)^2$
                                    & N'existe pas dans $\mathbb{R}$ \\
  \midrule
     $x$ & \xgt       & \xeq        & \xlt       \\
   $f(x)$& \fxgt{+}{-}& \fxeq{+}    & $+$        \\[1ex]
     $f$ & \fgta      & \feqa       & \flta      \\
  \midrule
     $x$ & \xgt       & \xeq        & \xlt       \\
   $f(x)$& \fxgt{-}{+}& \fxeq{-}    & $-$        \\[1ex]
     $f$ & \fgtb      & \feqb       & \fltb      \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Short explanation of what `\mynode` does: It is a wrapper for `\node`, to avoid having to repeat the formatting of the contents of the node. `\mynode` has three obligatory arguments: The first is the name of the node (to be used by `\draw` commands), the second are the coordinates of the node within the drawing, and the last is the contents of the node. The contents of the node is typeset by `\raisebox{0ex}[0.7ex][0ex]{$#3$}`. The `\raisebox` takes care that the node contents has a fixed height above the baseline (`0.7ex`) and a fixed depth below the baseline (the second `0ex`; the first one just says that the contents should not be raised). This is a trick to have `\infty`, `x_1` and `\alpha` on the same line; just remove the `\raisebox` command and see what happens. (tikz centers the contents of the node at the given coordinate. Since `x_1` extends below the baseline, it will be shifted up compared to `\alpha`.)

Comment: I've not the idea to have a 9x4 tabular because I don't know how to use `tikz` alone, and so use `tkz-tab` instead to do the job. But, from what i've seen, it's not made to have several tables, so use just `tikz` in a normal tabular is a better idea. And i've had some columns to your code, and it's working also very well. A question: how do you define `\mynode` command (with `\node` and `\raisebox`)?

Comment: @prosopopee I have added an explanation why I have defined `\mynode` this way. Regarding the tikz stuff I recommend to have a look at tutorials like [A very minimal introduction to TikZ](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf) by Jacques Crémer.